# Is it possible to extract a single folder from a corrupted zip archive

Tags: windows, backup, zip, 7-zip, archiving

I have a 22gb zip file which was located In a flash drive, I moved this archive to desktop but I am unable to extract it, it says the archive is corrupted. I used WinRAR to repair it but it didn't work, I used other tools and it was either the zip was too big or another problem, then I used WinZip, it shows unable to find local header. My main problem here is, inside the zip archive there is a folder containing a react native project I have worked on for more than a year, I really need that folder, if I am able to get that folder, I don't care about the rest of the files. Is there a way to copy or extract that folder? If there isn't, is there a way for me to access the Js files one by one to copy the codes inside?

I tried using extensions on vscode to access the Js files, it didn't show the contents and threw the error "invalid block" if I try to open any js file, I used vscode to copy the project folder to Desktop, but only filenames and folder names were copied.

I'm using windows 10 and there's no other copy of the files or the zip file, the zip file was meant to serve as a backup and my hard disk is formatted with a newly installed windows 10 so I can't access previous windows user files

Comment: Try sending the flash drive to a data recovery company. You made several cardinal errors. Learn from them. Never put the only copy of any data on such a fragile medium as flash or SD. Never zip data for long-term storage, thinking it's 'safe' [RAR & PAR2 might be forgivable, zip isn't]. You compounded your recovery process difficulty by many factors, just to save a bit of space.

Comment: Maybe you can  recover the file you had on your computer before formating with a recovery tool such as TestDisk or recuva.

Comment: try a zip repair program like https://repairit.wondershare.com/file-repair/how-to-repair-corrup-zip-file.html - theres a free trial

Comment: See also this post: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/repair-damaged-or-corrupted-zip-archive/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this from the command line, If the winrar path is not in the %path% variable you have to cd yourself to install folder of winrar first...

```
winrar.exe x -r YourZippedFolder.zip "FolderYouWant\*" "DestinyFolder"
```

Or to try to get the js files only:

```
winrar.exe x -r YourZippedFolder.zip *.js "DestinyFolder"
```

Answer (score -1):

Ahmad, I'm really sorry for your situation, but from what you've described, you can't recover the files or extract a single folder.

Please never back up your data only to a flash drive as it is very unreliable. Especially if we're talking about the project, you've worked on for a year. It is always best to keep your data in multiple destinations. The general recommendation is to use the 3-2-1-1 approach. However, if you don't want to go that professional, at least use both a cloud and a detachable drive.

Comment: this is just useless as an answer, especially since there are many tools for repairing zip files. They are at least worth a try !

Comment: They might be worth a try. But have you had any positive experiences with at least some of them? Me never. Sometimes you just have to accept what happened and learn from it. At least, that is what I think.

Comment: "All of the software tested was able to at least recover the undamaged files inside the corrupt archive. Some also recovered the damaged files although they were obviously still incomplete. If the corrupt files are images, for example, you might still be able to view them in their damaged state."
Read More: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/repair-damaged-or-corrupted-zip-archive/

Comment: Maybe I simply was the unlucky one, but everything I really needed to recover was usually damaged. However, you've got the point, obviously.